# matplotlib external docs in pycharm

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm

How do I add matplotlib external docs in pycharm?

so far tried adding

http://matplotlib.org/api/{module.name}_api.html#matplotlib.{module.name}.{element.name}

and

http://matplotlib.org/api/{class.name}_api.html#matplotlib.{class.name}.{function.name}

none of those works.. pycharm doesn't show the same kind of verbose docs as it does for numpy and standard libraries when I view external docs for functions and stuff....

*I am using pycharm version 3.0.2 with python 3.X*

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like:

http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/api/{module.name}_api.html#{element.qname}

I am using this configuration in my PyCharm and it seems to work. 
My PyCharm version is Community Edition 3.1

Comment: For something like `plt.plot`, `{module.name}` seems to return `matplotlib.pyplot`, whereas only `pyplot` is used on the website.

Comment: this now returns a 404

Answer (score 1):

Module Name: `matplotlib`

URL/Path Pattern: `https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/{module.name}.{element.name}.html#{module.name}.{element.name}`

... works for me (using PyCharm 2018.2.4).