# Does anyone have the "Documentation URL"s in PyCharm for the following libraries:

Tags: python, pycharm, code-documentation

I'm a fan of the "quick documentation" feature of PyCharm & other Jetbrains IDEs, but it needs to know the specific "Documentation URL" for each library, that gets set under `Preferences > Tools > Python External Documentation` settings.

I was wondering if anybody has worked it out for any of the following libraries:

- Tensorflow
- PyTorch
- Matplotlib
- Seaborn
- Pandas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These work for me (using PyCharm 2018.2.4):

#### Matplotlib

Module Name: [`matplotlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52516372/10134040)

URL/Path Pattern: `https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/{module.name}.{element.name}.html#{module.name}.{element.name}`

#### Pandas

Module Name: [`pandas`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52516473/10134040)

URL/Path Pattern: `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/{element.qname}.html#{element.qname}`

#### TensorFlow

(untested)

Module Name: [`tensorflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832805)

URL/Path Pattern: `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/{element.name}`

#### Seaborn

Module Name: `seaborn`

URL/Path Pattern: `https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/{module.name}.{element.name}.html#{module.name}.{element.name}`

#### scikit-learn

Module Name: [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html)

URL/Path Pattern: `https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/{element.qname}.html#{element.qname}`

Comment: For tensorflow and other libraries with irregular path, check https://gqqnbig.me/2020/11/18/pycharm-external-documentation-configurations/ which uses Chrome extension Requestly to properly construct the path.