# Unable to include external pandas docs Pycharm v--2018.1.2

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pycharm

I am not able to Include external pandas docs `Pycharm v--2018.1.2.`

for example :

```
numpy -> http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/{}generated/{module.name}{element.name}.html
```

Not working for in `pandas` and `matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

#### Pandas

Module Name: `pandas`

URL/Path Pattern: `https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.{element.name}.html#pandas.{element.name}`

... works for me (using PyCharm 2018.2.4).