# how to get quick documentation of a function in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently started working in pycharm. In jupyter notebook to find documentation of a function <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> would work but in pycharm I am not able to find.

I tried the following <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> its only working for inbuilt function like `print()`, `max()` but if I import a library its not working for it. for ex:

```
import cv2
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Its not telling any info or parameter for VideoCapture function and if I try to navigate it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> its showing "cannot find declaration to go" it also shows unresolved reference

I even checked with different library files like random, numpy but its not working

How should I resolve the problem

Comment: `ctrl + q` is the combination for docs

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777474/does-anyone-have-the-documentation-urls-in-pycharm-for-the-following-libraries

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + q or alt + middle-click
[pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTnhp.png)